# Visual Studio (Community 2019) does not enable MySQL for Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, mysql-connector

So I just installed MySQL yesterday and it installed with it MySQL for Visual Studio. But it crashed and then told me later that it crashed because of MySQL for Visual Studio, So I disabled it, thinking I'd reenable it when needed. But when I opened it today and enabled it gives error 
[image: error]

Please help

Comment: Enable the asp.net and web tools?

Comment: @dan1st but how

Comment: The same way as you want to enable mysql for vs?

Comment: @dan1st but there isn't an option for that in Extnsions->Manage Extensions which is where MySQL for vs is located

Comment: Whst about the marketplace?

Comment: @dan1st well i found it on the market place BUT on the web i.e. [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesEloff.MicrosoftASPNETandWebTools-9689) here but not on the visual studio app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218131/discussion-between-omer-hijazi-and-dan1st).